# Make an LED Turn

Tags: programming, code-review

```
//Make an LED Turn ON after pressing a push button switch for five times. Add a reset switch to turn OFF the LED whenever the reset switch is pressed

**void setup()

{
  
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);

  pinMode (4,INPUT);

}

void loop()

{

  int y= digitalRead(6); // push button 2

  static int counter {} ; 

  int x= digitalRead(4);// push button 1 

  if (x==1&& y==0 )
   
    counter++;

else if (counter == 5) // If counter is pressed 5 times

{

  digitalWrite(11, HIGH); // Turn on the LED

}

if (counter >= 5) // If counter is greater than 5 led will still on

{

  digitalWrite (11, 1);

 
}

  else if 

  
   (y==1&& x==0 ) // if pressed push button 2  led of 
  {

    digitalWrite(11,0);

  
}

  counter = 0; // Make counter variable = 0

}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that a school assignment? What have you tried so far? Where exactly is your problem in implementing this? Have you looked at some of the numerous tutorials online, which teach how to blink an LED and how to read buttons? Btw: For button reading I can suggest the Bounce2 library, which is really helpful

Comment: my problem i don't know how to make LED on after press push buttons five times

Comment: Remember using either a pullup resistor or `INPUT_PULLUP` in the `setup`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try implementing a counter system in your Arduino program.

For example, if this is your loop() function:

```
void loop(){
int buttonState = digitalRead(1); // Give the variable buttonState the value of pin 1, or whatever your button is connected to
static int counter{}; // Have a counter variable. Static means it doesn't reset to 0 after loop() restarts

if (buttonState == HIGH) // If the button is pressed
{
  ++counter; // Increase the value of counter by 1
}

else if (counter == 5) // If counter is pressed 5 times
{
  digitalWrite(11, HIGH); // Turn on the LED
}
// RESET:
if (counter > 5) // If counter is greater than 5 (you clicked the button again)
{
  digitalWrite (11, LOW);
  counter = 0; // Make counter variable = 0
}
}
```

*Edit* In the comments, Python Schlage made very good suggestions: to change `buttonState` to a boolean and change `int` to `byte` to save space on board the Arduino

Try following this tutorial: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Button and modifying it to work with the counter.
Hope this helps! Please let us know if you need help with the setup() function or if anything is unclear.

Comment: For saving memory, `buttonState` can be changed into a Boolean and counter can be a `byte`. The `else` part is pretty useless, because it will just turn the LED off all the time, although it already is on `LOW`.

Comment: Good points Python Schlange! I'll add in a modified version with your suggestions